# Bootstrap modal removeData option

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap modal box with remote option on my site. I have two ids of modal:

```
#myModal, #myModal2
```

and many content loaded with remote option for it.

After close callback for modal box I use this function:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            alert('only once')
            $(e.target).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").empty();
});
```

to remove modal and clear content for safety. But what is going wrong is that

```
alert('only once')
```

is called so many times how many times I open modal. For examle, after first close modal box I have only one alert. After open and close some next modal box I have two alerts and soo on... So this function doesn't remove modal box completely? How can I remove modal completely?

Comment: use one() instead of on()

Comment: hm ... but this is problem for every callbacks for this modal box ... everywhere I should use .one? I don't think that this is fix for this

Comment: one is used to call a function only once, so try that.

Comment: theoretically works ... just a little bit worries me that this modal, however, sits somewhere ..hm ...

Comment: Yeah, you have to change them.